# Don't load "edits.css" in Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My Wordpress theme loads a stylesheet with the name "edits.css" and ID "edits-css". I'm running a custom theme and therefore do not require Wordpress to load this file. How do I stop Wordpress from loading this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use child theme for dequeuing the style you are referring to

```
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_styles() {
wp_dequeue_style( 'bootstrap-map' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'bootstrap-map' );
}

add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_styles' );
```

For documentation : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove style like this:

```
function wp_67472455() {
   wp_dequeue_style( 'edit );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'wp_67472455', 100 );
```